# Требуется ли не ставить точку в подписи к фото на сайте?

Tags: пунктуация

Будет ли считаться ошибкой, если поставить точку в конце предложения, в том числе назывного, в подписи к иллюстративному фото на сайте?

Ведь это не противоречит тому, что сказано у Розенталя в РАЗДЕЛЕ 1
Знаки препинания в конце предложения и при перерыве речи
§ 1. Точка

Например:

Дональд Трамп на пресс-конференции в Вашингтоне. 25 сентября 2019 года.

Дональд Трамп. 25 сентября 2019 года.

Дональд Трамп.

Comment: Следите за метками, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, будет. Точка не ставится в конце заголовка или названия. Подписи под фотографиями к ним не относятся. 
Посмотрел старые газеты. Точки в подписях везде стоят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не очень хорошо видно, но разглядеть можно.

Судя по всему, отсутствие точек в подписи - новация совсем недавнего времени и никакими нормирующими источниками не подтвержденная.

**UPD**
К вопросу о точке в заголовке. Я её видел. Да, тогдашние правила подразумевали и это. В каких именно случаях - не могу сказать, но такое встречалось в газетах того времени. Не знаю, что тут добавить...
Но мы-то разбираемся с точкой в подписи под рисунками. По этой части, надеюсь, претензий к иллюстрациям нет.

**UPD-2** Посмотрел про точку в заголовке. Она ставилась как раз до 1924 г. включительно. В газетах 25 г. её уже нет.

Comment: В этом «доказательстве» и заголовок передовицы имеет точку.

Comment: @shampar  вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: В газете от 24-го года точка стоит в заголовке. Вы же пишете, что «не ставится». Вопрос: надо ли о том писать, о чём в вопросе не спрошено (точка ... в конце заголовка или названия)? Я бы убрал.

Comment: @shampar Не думаю, что здесь что-то не так. В те времена точка в заголовках ставилась.

Comment: Странность в том, что иллюстрация будто дана по логике «Так делать не надо».

Comment: @shampar я не вижу ни такой странности, ни такой логики.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:

> В подписи к иллюстрации точка обычно не ставится. Точка нужна лишь в
>   том случае, если подпись представляет собой цитату - завершенное
>   повествовательное предложение.
>   http://gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Здесь подробнее: http://www.apsolyamov.ru/blog/podrisunochnaja_podpis_kak_postavit_opisanie_k_izobrazheniju/2014-01-06-146